# Chaining AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehaviors in Wicket to single Javascript event

Tags: javascript, ajax, event-handling, dom-events, wicket

How to easily chain [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/)'s [AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior.html)s, so that several behaviors can be triggered from single Javascript event. I am using *Wicket 1.4*.

For example, when `onblur` event happens, I like these two behaviors to trigger. I am just concerned with triggering `onUpdate()` method. If I do this, it seems that only one behavior gets triggered. One way to achieve this is to have a single behavior that does both the *A* and *B* operations, but I am looking for something more composeable.

```
field.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onblur") {
   protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
      // do thing A here
      getComponent(); // behaviors need a reference to field they are attached to
   }
});
field.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onblur") {
   protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
      // do thing B here
   }
});
```

Comment: At worst, you can create a generic composite updating behavior class that accepts a list/array of other behaviors and calls all of them.

Comment: @biziclop: I was hoping that there were something like that ready made.

Answer (score 5):

This will be supported in Wicket 6.0.
But it is not a good practice because this way you will have 2 requests which are executed one by one. I recommend to have one behavior which does A and B.